# Getting Connection Refused error upon running openocd

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, debugging, esp32, openocd

I'm having a bit of trouble setting up an openocd debugger in Eclipse.

Upon running debug configurations, I get:

```
Error message from debugger back end:
localhost:3333: Connection refused.
Failed to execute MI command:
-target-select remote localhost:3333
```

This is what the debugger tab looks like:
[image]

Comment: Do you have a firewall or anyting blocking Port 3333?

Comment: I have firewall disabled